# ajax post not mapping parameters to asp.net controller action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, windows, iis

I have this weird issue. I just switched from develoment pc (win7 to win10) and when I run my website now (in debug) the parameters being posted by an ajax call are not being mapped to the parameters on the controller action. On my old development pc it is being mapped, but on my new one it just won't do it.

this is my ajax call:

```
      var obj = { companies: activeCompanyFilters, vesselTypes: activeVesselTypeFilters, vessels: activeVesselFilters, mapFilterType: getMapFilterType(), flushSession: flushSession };

    var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $("#filter-section").attr("data-source-link"),
        data: json,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: retrieveSuccess
    }).done(() => {
        layerChanged();
        if (indicator) {
            indicator.close();
        }
    });
```

this is the content being sent (captured with fiddler):

> {"companies":[],"vesselTypes":[],"vessels":[2317],"mapFilterType":1,"flushSession":false}

and this is my controller:

```
 [AjaxOnly]
    public JsonResult FilterMarkers(long[] companies, long[] vesselTypes, long[] vessels, int? mapFilterType, bool? flushSession)
    {
        if (flushSession.HasValue && flushSession.Value)
            Session["HomeSession"] = null;

        MapFilterType filterType = HomeControllerHelper.CastToMapFilterTypeOrDefault(mapFilterType, GetSidUser());


        var session = HomeControllerHelper.GetCurrentSession(Session, filterType);
        var filtered = MapFilter.FilterData(session.VesselDetails, companies, vesselTypes, vessels).ToList();

        return new JsonResult()
        {
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            Data = new
            {
                VesselDetails = filtered
            }
        };

    }
```

I don't know what I'm missing. And I know it works because it works on my old pc. Is there a setting in IIS I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Via visual studio you can create a virtual directory if you're using a local iis. i configured it like 'localhost/test'.
Things in the website are configured to Test.

so it was just a casing problem. Just strange only mapping failed but everything else worked